# Removing title from select query in PHP

Tags: php, json, sqlite, select-query

Is there any way to select a table in SQLite without printing the column headers?

The following is the code I am using:

```
SELECT realPow, timestamp 
FROM PowerData;

//To loop through the table and fetch the data for Real power
while($res = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    $equal[] = $res;
}
echo json_encode($meArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Result:

```
[{"realPow":50,"timestamp":1391990400},{"realPow":200,"timestamp":1392422400},
{"realPow":100,"timestamp":1394409600},{"realPow":150,"timestamp":1395273600},
{"realPow":140,"timestamp":1397952000},{"realPow":130,"timestamp":1398384000},
{"realPow":120,"timestamp":1400544000},{"realPow":90,"timestamp":1402358400},
{"realPow":100,"timestamp":1402790400}]
```

I want to remove the "realPow:"  & "timestamp:".

Comment: `$equal[] = array($res['realPow'], $res['timestamp']);`

Comment: The answer is literally in the documentation. Check the parameters of [fetchArray.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your code modified:

```
SELECT realPow, timestamp FROM PowerData;

    //To loop through the table and fetch the data for Real power
    while($res = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        $equal[] = array($res['realPow'], $res['timestamp']);
    }
    echo json_encode($meArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: No problem :). If it was useful, please consider accpeting the answer. Thank you!